# не могу понять фрагмент кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю python по Лутцу. Столкнулся с примером кода, логику которого, немогу понять до конца. Пример кода:

```
def Tracer(classname, supers, classdict):
    print('Tracer')
    aClass = type(classname, supers, classdict)
    class Wrapper:
        print('Wrapper')
        def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
            print('__init__ Wrapper', args)
            self.wrapped = aClass(*args, **kargs)
        def __getattr__(self, attrname):
            print('Trace', attrname)
            return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)
    return Wrapper
class Person(metaclass=Tracer):
    print('Person')
    def __init__(self, name, hours, rate):
        print('__init__ Person')
        self.name = name
        self.hours = hours
        self.rate = rate
    def pay(self):
        return self.hours * self.rate
bob = Person('Bob', 40, 50)
#print()
#print(bob.wrapped.name)
```

Очевидно, что до момента, присвоения классу Person экземпляра(командой `bob = Person('Bob', 40, 50)`), поток выполнения сначала заходит в Person и выполняет команду `print('Person')`, после чего в нижней части класса Person неявно выполняется ф-я Tracer(...), которая является метаклассом и возвращает ссылку на класс Wrapper(и выполняет команду `print('Wrapper')`), т.е. по итогу выполнения Tracer(...) мы получаем неявную ссылку на класс Wrapper, внизу класса Person.

Теперь что мне непонятно.

Почему, после того, как выполняется команда `bob = Person('Bob', 40, 50)`, у нас запускается конструктор `Wrapper.__init__(...)`, а не `Person.__init__(...)`? Не могу понять как `Wrapper.__init__(...)` может перехватывать аргументы('Bob', 40, 50), если конструктор `Person.__init__(...)`, расположен в классе Person выше, чем неявная ссылка на Wrapper, которая находиться в самом низу класса Person, а питон читает код сверху-вниз?

Comment: Нет никакой неявной ссылки на "Wrapper внизу класса Person". По мере прохождения заполняется пространство имен, где метакласс подменяет класс, но в пространство имен он попадает как Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По шагам.

1. В пространство имен модуля попадает функция Tracer.
2. Выполнение дошло до определения класса Person и его код выполняется. Каждый def дополняет словарь атрибутов именами методов. Если в классе нет кода, кроме определения методов, то порядок значения не имеет.
3. По результату выполнения шага 2 получаем имя 'Person' и набор атрибутов. И вместо конструирования класса среда выполнения делегирует эту операцию метаклассу (тому, что указано как метакласс)
4. Метакласс (в данном случае это функция Tracer) с помощью `type()` конструирует на основе переданных данных (имя, атрибуты...) класс Person, а также определяет класс Wrapper, где и используется этот класс Person. При этом **возвращает класс Wrapper**, который и попадает в пространство имен модуля под именем Person.
5. То есть с этого момента у нас под именем Person на самом деле класс Wrapper и потому `Person('Bob', 40, 50)` создает инстанс класса Wrapper и вызывает `Wrapper.__init__`, который пишет в консоль, а затем внутри себя создает экземпляр класса `Person` и вызывает `Person.__init__`